# Building an ILIKE clause from an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm experimenting with a few concepts (actually playing and learning by building a RoR version of the 1978 database WHATSIT?).

It basically is a has_many :through structure with Subject -> Tags <- Value. I've tried to replicate a little of the command line structure by using a query text field to enter the commands. Basically things like: `What's steve's phone`.

Anyhow, with that interface most of the searches use ILIKE. I though about enhancing it by allowing OR conditions using some form of an array. Something like `What's steve's [son,daugher]`. I got it working by creating the ILIKE clause directly, but not with string replacement.

```
def bracket_to_ilike(arrel,name,bracket)
  bracket_array = bracket.match(/\[([^\]]+)\]/)[1].split(',')
  like_clause = bracket_array.map {|i| "#{name} ILiKE '#{i}' "}.join(" OR ")
  arrel.where(like_clause)
 end
```

`bracket_to_ilike(tags,'tags.name','[son,daughter]')` produces the like clause `tags.name ILiKE 'son'  OR tags.name ILiKE 'daughter'`

And it get the relations, but with all the talk about using the form  `("tags.name ILiKE ?  OR tags.name ? ",v1,v2,vN..)`., I though I'd ask if anyone has any ideas on how to do that.

Creating variables on the fly is doable from what I've searched, but not in favor. I just wondered if anyone has tried creating a method that can add a where clause that has a variable number parameters.I tried sending the where clause to the relation, but it didn't like that.

Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Phillip for pointing me in the right direction.

- I didn't know you could pass an array to a where clause - that opened up some options
- I had used the splat operator a few times, but it didn't hit me that it actually creates an object(variable)

The [son,daughter] stuff was just a console exercise to see what I could do, but not sure what I was going to do with it. I ended up taking the model association and creating the array out of the picture and implemented OR searches.

```
def array_to_ilike(col_name,keys)
  ilike = [keys.map {|i| "#{col_name} ILiKE ? "}.join(" OR "), *keys ]
  #ilike = [keys.size.times.map{"#{col_name} ILIKE ?"}.join(' OR '), *keys ]
  #both work, guess its just what you are use to.
end
```

I then allowed a pipe(|) character in my subject,tag,values searches, so a WHATSIT style question

- `What's Steve's Phone Home|Work` => displays home and work phone
- `steve phone home|work` The 's stuff is just for show
- `steve son|daughter`  => displays children
- `phone james%|lori%` => displays phone number for anyone who's name starts with james or lori
- `james%|lori%`  => dumps all information on anyone who's name starts with james or lori

The query then parses the command and if it encounters a | in any of the words, it will do things like:

```
t_ilike = array_to_ilike('tags.name',name.split("|"))
# or I actually stored it off on the inital parse
t_ilike = @tuple[:tag][:ilike] ||= ['tags.name ilike ?',tag]
```

Again this is just a learning exercise in creating a non-CRUD class to deal with the parsing and searching.

Steve

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to watch out for in your code...

- What will happen when one of the elements of bracket_array contains a single quote?
- What will happen if I take it step farther and set an element to say "'; drop tables..."?

My first stab at refactoring your code would be to see if Arel can do it.  Or Sequeel, or whatever they call the "metawhere" gem these days.  My second stab would be something like this:

```
arrel.where( [ bracket_array.size.times.map{"#{name} ILIKE ?"}.join(' OR '), *bracket_array ])
```

I didn't test it, but the idea is to use the size of bracket_array to generate a string of OR'd conditions, then use the splat operator to pass in all the values.

Comment: Your getting me closer, but the times loop is returning a fixed number and giving and error on the join. Going back to my map loop and using the splat it give the right like clause and variable. At first it was giving me an And clause, but I think because my tags instance was messed up. `tags.where(*[bracket_array.map {|i| "#{name} ILiKE ? "}.join(" OR "), *bracket_array ])` worked. Now I just have to understand why where will take an array argument.  Again this experiment was to learn a little more Ruby.

Comment: @appleII717  Yep, you're right.  I should have had `bracket_array.size.times.map` (missing the .map) instead. I've updated my post.